# Formulate and solve a system of linear, first-order ODEs in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, scripting

I know this code is wrong, but I am not sure why. I have a system of coupled differential equations. The model is given by the following equations:

$\frac{dS_0} {dt} = (1 - \mu_0) \rho_0 S_0 \frac{S_\gamma}{S_\rho} - \gamma_0 S_0$

$\frac{dS_1} {dt} = \mu_0 \rho_0 S_0 \frac{S_\gamma}{S_\rho} - \gamma_1 S_1 + (1 - \mu_1) \rho_1 S_1 \frac{S_\gamma}{S_\rho}$

$\vdots$

$\frac{dS_n}{dt} = \mu_{n-1} \rho_{n-1} S_{n-1} \frac{S_\gamma}{S_\rho} + (1-\mu_n) \rho_n S_n  \frac{S_\gamma}{S_\rho} - \gamma_n S_n$.

Caveat: $\frac{S_\gamma}{S_\rho}$ is a constant term that scales cell birth and cell death rates over all life-stages so the population size remains constant over time.
I thought it should be simple to solve the system with Mathematica because I have solved the simplest cases of the ODE system by hand (the 2-stage and 3-stage models) and have an idea that if I put it into matrix form correctly, it will have a triangular structure. Here's my code:

```
(*Change the recursion limit on Wolfram Mathematica on the Cloud*)
(* Define the number of stages *)
n = 2;
(* Define the state vector *)
S = Array[s, n];
(* Define the coefficient vectors *)
\[Mu] = Array[\[Mu], n];
\[Rho] = Array[\[Rho], n];
\[Gamma] = Array[\[Gamma], n];
(* Define the coefficient matrices *)
A = DiagonalMatrix[-\[Gamma]];
B = DiagonalMatrix[(1 - \[Mu]) \[Rho]];
(* Define the derivative of the state vector *)
dSdt = D[S[t], t];
(* Construct the derivative in terms of matrices A and B *)
ode = dSdt == A.S + B.S \[Gamma]/S \[Rho];
(* Define the initial condition vector *)
S0 = {1, 0}; (* First stage = 1, others = 0 *)
(* Solve the ODE system with the initial condition *)
solution = DSolve[{ode, S[0] == S0}, S[t], t]
```

If there are n=2 stages, there should be two coupled ODEs; if there are three stages, there should be three coupled ODEs. Is this an inefficient way to input everything to make a matrix ODE system? It seems the way I have formed the matrix ODE system here is either incorrect or missing something because when I run `DSolve`, it returns it unevaluated. The error message output is: "Function S appears with no arguments." I have searched here a few times to find the best way to formulate similar problems but haven't found anything that jumped out at me as a good way to correct my code.

Comment: you can not type `\[Mu] = Array[\[Mu], n]`  because you will get infinite recursion    ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8hdY.png)

Comment: Ah OK! That explains the recursion wall! Thank you!

Comment: I changed those 3 lines to the format of "Table[\[Mu]i, {i, n}];" which could be more sensible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting all over again as correct equations posted.

Since Mathematica index starts from 1 and not zero, it is easier to start your equations from 1 and not 0 as you showed.

Let $\beta=\frac{S_{\gamma}}{S_{\rho}}$ a constant. Then

\begin{align*}
S_{1}^{\prime}  & =\left(  1-\mu_{1}\right)  \rho_{1}S_{1}\beta-\gamma
_{1}S_{1}\\
S_{2}^{\prime}  & =\mu_{1}\rho_{1}S_{1}\beta-\gamma_{2}S_{2}+\left(  1-\mu
_{2}\right)  \rho_{2}S_{2}\beta\\
S_{3}^{\prime}  & =\mu_{2}\rho_{2}S_{2}\beta-\gamma_{3}S_{3}+\left(  1-\mu
_{3}\right)  \rho_{3}S_{3}\beta\\
& \vdots\\
S_{n}^{\prime}  & =\mu_{n-1}\rho_{n-1}S_{n-1}\beta-\gamma_{n}S_{n}+\left(
1-\mu_{n}\right)  \rho_{n}S_{n}\beta
\end{align*}

In Matrix form the above becomes

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
S_{1}^{\prime}\\
S_{2}^{\prime}\\
S_{3}^{\prime}\\
\vdots\\
S_{n}^{\prime}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\gamma_{1}+\left(  1-\mu_{1}\right)  \rho_{1}\beta & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots
& 0\\
\mu_{1}\rho_{1}\beta & -\gamma_{2}+\left(  1-\mu_{2}\right)  \rho_{2}\beta &
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
0 & \mu_{2}\rho_{2}\beta & -\gamma_{3}+\left(  1-\mu_{3}\right)  \rho_{3}\beta
& 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \mu_{n-1}\rho_{n-1}\beta & -\gamma_{n}+\left(  1-\mu
_{n}\right)  \rho_{n}\beta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
S_{1}\\
S_{2}\\
S_{3}\\
\vdots\\
S_{n}%
\end{pmatrix}
$$

To generate this in Mathematica, a simple loop will do.

```
n = 2;
S = Array[s, n]
S = Map[#[t] &, S]
dSdt = Map[D[#, t] &, S]
μArray = Array[μ, n]
ρArray = Array[ρ, n]
γArray = Array[γ, n]
eqs = First@Last@Reap@Do[z = (-γArray[[m]] + 
     (1 - μArray[[m]])*ρArray[[m]]*β)*S[[m]]; 
     If[m > 1, z = z + (μArray[[m - 1]]*ρArray[[m - 1]]*β)*S[[m - 1]]]; 
     Sow[dSdt[[m]] == z], {m, 1, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solve

```
  DSolve[eqs, S, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here it is for n=3

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solve

```
 DSolve[eqs, S, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is for n=6

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and so on.

### old answer

Try this and see if this is what you meant

```
n = 2;
S = Array[s, n]
S = Map[#[t] &, S]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
μArray = Array[μ, n]
ρArray = Array[ρ, n]
γArray = Array[γ, n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
A = DiagonalMatrix[-μArray]
B = DiagonalMatrix[(1 - μArray)  ρArray]
dSdt = Map[D[#, t] &, S]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ode = Thread[dSdt == A . S + B . S  γArray/S  ρArray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
S0 = {1, 0}
ic = MapThread[(#1 == #2) /. t -> 0 &, {S, S0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
solution = DSolve[{ode, ic}, S, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This looks like it! And I can seen now that the "map" and "thread" parts are very useful here. I'll have to read up on them in the tech specs. Thank you, Nasser! I don't use this site often enough to upvote your answer, yet. But I will as I soon as my reputation goes up! *Rifles through a pad of computations, looking for a particular computation...* Yeah these look a lot like what I was expecting but I will compare to my original pen-and-paper work and see if I myself got something similar for the small number of cases that are tractable to calculate by hand.

Comment: This is very close to what I was thinking of, I just can't figure out the correction so it's actually solving my model. What I've got here, is almost my complete model. In stage 2, here s[2][t], there should be a coefficient term from s[1][t] since they're coupled differential equations. So, I'm at the drawing board trying to figure out the corrections I need to make to the coefficient vectors.

Comment: @BenHardisty if you look at your ode's. they are _not_ coupled. `s1` ode does depend on `s2`, and `s2` ode does not depends on `s1`. I just used the same equations you had.  May be if you can post the ode's in Latex to see what is the problem. if these odes are from a book, you can post screen shot.

Comment: @BenHardisty I can't read your equations easily. Better posting them in your question so  they show more clearly. I also do not know what `Sγ` is and what is `Sρ` as these do not show in your code you showed.

Comment: Thanks User444 and Nasser for both forcing me to clarify and do some editing!

Comment: Thank you very much @Nasser ! I came up with a way too, after a coffee break, using some of your prior code & some new code, but not as elegant as yours.